# Display ul next to each other

Tags: html, css

I have multiply UL lists, and I need them to be next to each other horizontal instead of vertical.

This is my css:

```
   .tags:before,.tags:after{content:'';display:table}
   .tags:after{clear:both}
   .tags{margin-left:38%;}
   .tags li{position:relative;float:left;margin:0 0 8px 12px;list-style-type: none;}
   .tags li:active{margin-top:1px;margin-bottom:7px}
   .tags li:after{content:'';z-index:2;position:absolute;top:10px;right:-2px;width:5px;height:6px;opacity:.95;background:#eb6b22;border-radius:3px 0 0 3px;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 1px 0 #99400e;box-shadow:inset 1px 0 #99400e}
   .tags a,.tags span{display:block;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}
   .tags a{height:26px;line-height:23px;padding:0 9px 0 8px;font-size:12px;color:#555;text-decoration:none;text-shadow:0 1px white;background:#fafafa;border-width:1px 0 1px 1px;border-style:solid;border-color:#dadada #d2d2d2 #c5c5c5;border-radius:3px 0 0 3px;background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fcfcfc,#f0f0f0);background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#fcfcfc,#f0f0f0);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#fcfcfc,#f0f0f0);background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,#fcfcfc,#f0f0f0);-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.7),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.7),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05)}
   .tags a:hover span{padding:0 7px 0 6px;max-width:40px;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.15),1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.15),1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)}
   .tags span{position:absolute;top:1px;left:100%;z-index:2;overflow:hidden;max-width:0;height:24px;line-height:21px;padding:0 0 0 2px;color:white;text-shadow:0 -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);background:#eb6b22;border:1px solid;border-color:#d15813 #c85412 #bf5011;border-radius:0 2px 2px 0;opacity:.95;background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#ed7b39,#df5e14);background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#ed7b39,#df5e14);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#ed7b39,#df5e14);background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,#ed7b39,#df5e14);-webkit-transition:.3s ease-out;-moz-transition:.3s ease-out;-o-transition:.3s ease-out;transition:.3s ease-out;-webkit-transition-property:padding,max-width;-moz-transition-property:padding,max-width;-o-transition-property:padding,max-width;transition-property:padding,max-width}
```

And my HTML:

```
 <ul class='tags greentag'><li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick="document.rent.refs.value='20';document.rent.submit(); return false;" id='refpack20'>20 <span>Rent</span></a></li></ul>
                       <ul class='tags greentag'><li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick="document.rent.refs.value='20';document.rent.submit(); return false;" id='refpack20'>20 <span>Rent</span></a></li></ul>
                       <ul class='tags greentag'><li><a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick="document.rent.refs.value='20';document.rent.submit(); return false;" id='refpack20'>20 <span>Rent</span></a></li></ul>
```

Currently each UL is placed vertical, and not horizontal as I want it to be. How can I obtain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make one of your UL's classes to have a `float:left;` or `display:inline-block;` style

Comment: `UL` _class_? Do you mean tag or element? +1 though.

Comment: yes class, each of his UL objects have 2 classes `tags` and `greentag` so all he needs to do is edit either of the classes and done.

Answer (score 0):

If you just float the `ul`s, the result won't be too pretty, due to the huge left margin on each one. Either remove or greatly reduce the left margin to ensure that they will all sit site by side:

```
.tags {
    margin-left: 20%;  /* play with this until happy */
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
}
```